# Content to slide in from right between menu and footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

Another question from me here. I'm building this [site](http://www.marcusnoren.nu).
Menu and footer are done (for now) and I have come to the point of adding the space to put my content in. 
I want the content to slide in from right between the menu and the footer (see below).
Ex. If I press contact, the contact page slides in from right and etc.

I don't know where to upload my source files. But if you need them you can also say where I should upload them. I didn't wanna upload 'em to my site because you may think it is a virus or something.

```
*********************************
*           menu                *
*********************************
*                           <---*
*      content sliding      <---*
*      in from right        <---*
*      when press link      <---*
*      on menu              <---*
*                           <---*
*                           <---*
*                           <---*
*********************************
*           footer              *
*********************************
```

Thank you so much for your time and help I would really appreciate it.

Marcus

Comment: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/hb3fjbj68cgyalw/website+.rar) to download source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, add these:

**HTML**

```
<!-- This is your sidebar -->
<aside id="cont_bar" class="hide"></aside>
```

**CSS**

```
/*This styles the sidebar, and adds classes to control display*/
#cont_bar {
    width: 16.6%;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: .60;
    margin-top: 36px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    transition: right .8s;
    -moz-transition: right .8s;
    -webkit-transition: right .8s;
}

.hide {
    right: -100%;
}

.unhide {
    right: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
/*Need this for event handling, works with jquery 1.6.4(included in your files) */
window.onload = function() {

    var winHeight = $(window).height(); //window height
    var footHeight = $('#footerwrapper').height(); //footer height
    $('#cont_bar').css( 'height', winHeight - 3.5*(footHeight) ); //sets sidebar height

    var getit = $('#contact');
    $(getit).bind( "click", function() {

        $('#cont_bar').toggleClass( "hide unhide" );

    });

}
```

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention quite a bit..
So first off, this requires javascript and jQuery.
Secondly, I gave your contact button (li) an id of `contact`.
Lastly, this is by no means a perfect solution but it should give you something to think about and hopefully a nudge in the right direction.

The code here creates a container to be your sidebar `<aside id="cont_bar">`.
It creates classes to handle hiding, unhiding and the transition to create the sliding effect.
 js is used to calculate the height of the sidebar, add and remove classes, and to set an event handler (click) on your Contact button (now `id="contact"`).

Comment: Thank you Ricky. Just one more question, on the button links should I write like <a href "#contact">?

Comment: No, that's not necessary. You can leave it as is, just add the `id` to it so it can be identified quickly.

Comment: Correct. Sorry I forgot to make that a little clearer in my description.

Comment: Thank you Ricky, awsome!

Comment: You're quite welcome. If you have any other questions, feel free to email me too. I learn by seeing how much I can teach. It's a win win lol

Comment: When i write <li id="contact"> the button disapears. You know why? Should I add <li id="contact class="something">? Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't disappear.. is the `.hide` class being included on it? Can you check this in the web inspector/firebug or whatever you use in your web browser?

Comment: i have a new menu now. you can check it on my site. marcusnoren.nu. I just found out when I deleted my <a href=""> links from the menu. thats when the button disapeared

Comment: should I put the js script in the same document or in a separate js file?

Comment: As a general rule of good practice, you should always separate your scripts to separate file. As for your button, my browser still shows the button (using Chrome and Firefox). Have you tested this with other browsers? Removing the `href=""` will only have an effect if something else is relying on it.

Comment: i havent uploaded it since i removed the a href link. here is the menu http://codepen.io/netpixel/pen/ItkGb

Comment: I apologize again.. I am at work and am juggling all kinds of things.. an anchor needs the `href` attribute to be recognized. If you want, you can remove the `#` and leave it blank like this: `href=""`.

Comment: like <li id="contact"> <a href="">contact</a></li>

Comment: Yes. Btw, stackoverflow tries to avoid lengthy discussions here. Anyway you could send these questions via email? -> vulpcod3z@gmail.com   I don't want to stir moderators..

Comment: Ok got it! Anyway Ricky, you're a really  nice person. Thank you!